# Rewrite HTTP to HTTPS Django

Tags: python, django, nginx, stripe-payments

I currently have a Django web server where I need to have users access through HTTPS. I went through this link [Django HTTP to HTTPS](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8964/trying-to-make-a-django-based-site-use-https-only-not-sure-if-its-secure) and understand I need to implement a rewrite rule but am unsure about which file to modify.

Here is the code snippet in nginx:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
}
```

Although, I am confused as to where this would be placed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Reason for all of this is I am implementing an iOS e-commerce application that uses Stripe Connect. But I need to supply an HTTPS redirect URI, not HTTP.

***EDIT***

So I am trying to go through the tutorial http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html but am getting stuck when adding `nginx`.

Installing is no problem, but its mainly the part where Im linking uWSGI and nginx together.

The step where I implement `mysite_nginx.conf` is confusing to me. I already added `uwsgi_params` to my django project root directory, so thats steps all good. But i feel my problem is linking nginx to the `mysite_nginx.conf` file. I linked the file to the /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ directory but once I run the server `uwsgi --socket :8001 --wsgi-file test.py`, then direct the web browser to port 8000, test.py isn't being rendered, the typical nginx intro template is being rendered. I have setup nginx to serve to port 8000 as well.

So I've followed the tutorial very explicitly, i feel, but am getting stuck on the part `nginx and uWSGI and test.py`

Any help would be awesome! Also, I am using Mac OS not Linux

Comment: Do you want to do this in nginx or in django? In django, use a middleware, in nginx, well, use that snippet. But Django should be behind nginx or some other server anyway, which is probably a better location to include the rewrite.

Comment: That rewrite belongs in nginx, but you'll also need to set up other stuff too. Here's a good guide on how to do this: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

Comment: So i decided to go with the good old Apache Solution and was able to get it working. Thanks guys for your input! I greatly appreciate it